# django Submit function does not save data in database

Tags: python, html, django, web-applications

I just started using django and this is my first app.
i created "contact form" depending on several tutorials i'v seen, but it doesn't save data to database nor direct me to the "Thank you" html page.

tried many scenarios but none worked
can anyone help?
i'm open to change any thing in the code just to make it work and save the data that i need to save.

setting.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp',
    # 'crispy_forms',
    'widget_tweaks',
```

models.py

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.conf import settings
    from datetime import date
    
    
    class Snippet(models.Model):
    
        MALE = 'MA'
        FEMALE = 'FE'
    
        GENDER_CHOICES = [
            (MALE, 'Male'),
            (FEMALE, 'Female'),
        ]



    LOCAL = 'SA'
    NONE_LOCAL  = 'NS'

    NAT_CHOICES = [
        (LOCAL, 'Local'),
        (NONE_LOCAL, 'Non_Local'),
    ]

    RIYADH = 'RH'
    JEDDAH = 'JH'

    CITY_CHOICES = [
        (RIYADH, 'Riyadh'),
        (JEDDAH, 'Jeddah'),
    ]


    DIPLOMA = 'DP'
    BACHELOR = 'BA'
    HIGHEREDU = 'HE'
    OTHER = 'OT'

    EDU_CHOICES = [
        (DIPLOMA, 'Diploma'),
        (BACHELOR, 'Bachelor'),
        (HIGHEREDU, 'Higer Edu'),
        (OTHER, 'Other'),
    ]

    ONE = 'On'
    FIVE = 'Fi'
    OTHER = 'Ot'
    INC_CHOICES = [
        (ONE, '100-500'),
        (FIVE, '500-1000'),
        (OTHER, 'Other'),
    ]

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
    mobile = models.IntegerField(default=None)

    gender = models.CharField(
        max_length=2, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default=MALE)

    nat = models.CharField(
        max_length=2, choices=NAT_CHOICES, default=LOCAL)

    city = models.CharField(
        max_length=2, choices=CITY_CHOICES, default=RIYADH)

    dob = models.DateField(default=None)



    edu = models.CharField(
        max_length=2, choices=EDU_CHOICES, default=OTHER)

    major = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    inc = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=INC_CHOICES, default=ONE)



    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {}'.format(self.name, self.email, self.mobile, self.gender in {self.MALE, self.FEMALE}, self.dob, self.nat in {self.LOCAL, self.NONE_LOCAL}, self.city in {self.RIYADH, self.JEDDAH}, self.edu in {self.DIPLOMA, self.BACHELOR, self.HIGHEREDU, self.OTHER}, self.major, self.inc in {self.ONE, self.FIVE, self.OTHER})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.home),
    path('form/', views.contact),
    path('home/', views.home),
    path('thank/', views.thank),
    path('about/', views.about),
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Snippet
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator


class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email')
    mobile = forms.IntegerField(label='Mobile', required=True)
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=[('select', 'Select'), ('male', 'Male'), ('female', 'female')])
    dob = forms.DateField(required=False)
    nat = forms.ChoiceField(label='Nationality',
                            choices=[('select', 'Select'), ('Local', 'Local'), ('non-Local', 'Non-Local')]) 
    city = forms.ChoiceField(label='City',
                            choices=[('select', 'Select'), ('riyadh', 'Riyadh'), ('jeddah', 'Jeddah')])
    edu = forms.ChoiceField(label='Education',
                            choices=[('select', 'Select'), ('diploma', 'Diploma'), ('bachelor', 'Bachelor'), ('higher edu', 'Higher Edu'), ('other', 'Other')])
    major = forms.CharField(label='Major', required=False)
    inc = forms.ChoiceField(label='Income', choices=[('select', 'Select'), (
        '1000-5000', '1000-5000'), ('5000-10000', '5000-10000'), ('other', 'Other')])

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    
class SnippetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'mobile', 'gender', 'dob',
                'nat', 'city', 'edu', 'major', 'inc',)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import ContactForm, SnippetForm
from .models import Snippet
from django.db import models


def contact(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
        
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            mobile = form.cleaned_data['mobile']
            gender = form.cleaned_data['gender']
            dob = form.cleaned_data['dob']
            nat = form.cleaned_data['nat']
            city = form.cleaned_data['city']
            edu = form.cleaned_data['edu']
            major = form.cleaned_data['major']
            inc = form.cleaned_data['inc']
            form.save()

            print(name, email, mobile, gender, dob, nat, city, edu, major, inc)

            return snippet_detail(request.POST)

    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)

        return render(request, 'myapp/form.html', {'form': form})


def snippet_detail(request):

    if (request.method == 'POST') and ("submit" in request.POST):
        form = SnippetForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    form = SnippetForm()

    return render(request, 'myapp/form.html', {'form': form})


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'myapp/home.html')


def about(request):
    return render(request, 'myapp/about.html')


def thank(request):
    return render(request, 'myapp/thank.html')
```

form.html

```
    {% extends 'myapp/main.html' %}</em>
    {% load widget_tweaks %}

    <em><!DOCTYPE html></em>
    <html lang="en">

    
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Registeration</title>
    <body>

        {% block content %}
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="Container">
            <h3>
                Registeration Form
            </h3>
        <hr>
    </div>
        <section class="section">
            <div class="Container">
                <div class="Columns">
                    <div class="Column is-half is-offset-one-quarter">
                        <div class="field">
                            <p>
                            <label class="label">Name</label>
                            <div class="control">
                                {% render_field form.name class="input" placeholder="Your name" %}
                            </div>
                            </p>
                        </div>

                        <p>   
                        <div class="field">
                            <label class="label">Email</label>
                            <div class="control">
                                {% render_field form.email class="input" placeholder="Your@email.com" %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </p>

                        <p>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label class="label">Mobile</label>
                            <div class="control">
                                {% render_field form.mobile class="input" placeholder="Your Mobile" %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </p>

                        <p>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label class="label">Gender</label>
                            <div class="control">
                                <div class="select">
                                    {% render_field form.gender %}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </p>

                            <p>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label class="label">Date of Birth</label>
                                <div class="control">
                                    {% render_field form.dob class="input" placeholder="Please Select" %}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </p>

                            <p>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label class="label">Nationality</label>
                                <div class="control">
                                    <div class="select">
                                        {% render_field form.nat %}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </p>

                            <p>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label class="label">City</label>
                                <div class="control">
                                    <div class="select">
                                        {% render_field form.city %}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </p>

                            <p>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label class="label">Edu</label>
                                <div class="control">
                                    <div class="select">
                                        {% render_field form.edu %}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </p>

                            <p>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label class="label">Major</label>
                                <div class="control">
                                    <div class="select">
                                        {% render_field form.major class="input" placeholder="Your Major" %}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </p>

                            <p>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label class="label">Income</label>
                                <div class="control">
                                    <div class="select">
                                        {% render_field form.inc %}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </p>

                            <p>
                            <div class="field is-grouped">
                                <div class="control">
                                    <button class="button" is-link="thank.html">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        
    </body>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </html>    
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: I thought form is supposed to be defined inside <form> </form> tag. I don't see it in your form.html

Comment: thanks for your reply
I changed the whole thing and it worked